# Multiple Value Fields and Repeat Control in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have 5 fields and each field has 10 values. I can be more than 10 or less. 
I want to list them in a table but I may look like this below. I think repeat control can do this but I am not sure how to handle this.

TITLE1       TITLE2      TITLE2     TITLE2      TITLE2
Field1[0]   Field2[0]   Field3[0]  Field5[0]   Field5[0]
Field1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LwM.png)   Field2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LwM.png)   Field3[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LwM.png)  Field5[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LwM.png)   Field5[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56LwM.png) 
 
Field1[2]   Field2[2]   Field3[2]  Field5[2]   Field5[2]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

I did it with table, repeat control and computedFields. The code is really long not to send :( [image: Screenshot of Multiple Valued Fields with Repeat Control]

I could only one repeat control code. So it can be copied to multiple

`<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="0" var="rowData">
<xp:link escape="true" value="#{rowData}" id="link1" target="_blank" styleClass="links"> <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:return link; </xp:link>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var links = document1.getItemValue("fieldName");
return "../../"+sessionScope.zaman_db_Path + "/xspFrmName.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=" + links;}]]></xp:this.value><br /></xp:repeat>`

Comment: Do you want to edit each value separately, or is it just output?

Comment: No, I don't. It's just an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table then put my design elements in it. 
I will share my code asap.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the maximum number of rows - so count number of values in every field and get maximum of it. That's your row count and feed it to repeat in form of {1, 2, 3, .... max}.

Repeat contains five fields with binding: if my number of values is less than current row count, show nothing. Else show i-th value of the current field.

That will render your table.

Comment: by the way I did it with repeat control :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did it with table, repeat control and computedFields. The code is really long not to send :( [image: Screenshot of Multiple Valued Fields with Repeat Control]

I could only one repeat control code. So it can be copied to multiple

`<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="0" var="rowData">
<xp:link escape="true" value="#{rowData}" id="link1" target="_blank" styleClass="links"> <xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:return link; </xp:link>
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var links = document1.getItemValue("fieldName");
return "../../"+sessionScope.zaman_db_Path + "/xspFrmName.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=" + links;}]]></xp:this.value><br /></xp:repeat>`

Answer (score 0):

You can play with nested table elements and repeats, like this:

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="0" var="rowData" indexVar="rowi">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="0" var="colData" indexVar="coli">
                <xp:td>
                    ...
                </xp:td>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:table>
```